# Who is the 'one who had lifted it' in Shelley's sonnet about 'the painted veil'?

Tags: poetry, allusions, percy-bysshe-shelley

In Shelley's famous sonnet, which begins **'Lift not the painted veil'**, the "turn" is placed - unusually - in the seventh line.

> Lift not the painted veil which those who live
> Call Life: though unreal shapes be pictured there,
> And it but mimic all we would believe
> With colours idly spread,—behind, lurk Fear
> And Hope, twin Destinies; who ever weave
> Their shadows, o'er the chasm, sightless and drear.
> I knew **one who had lifted it**—he sought,
> For his lost heart was tender, things to love,
> But found them not, alas! nor was there aught
> The world contains, the which he could approve.
> Through the unheeding many he did move,
> A splendour among shadows, a bright blot
> Upon this gloomy scene, a Spirit that strove
> For truth, and like the Preacher found it not.

In this line, the poet mentions **'one who had lifted it'**, and then goes on to describe some of the miseries of that person's unhappy life. **Are there any interesting theories as to who that person might have been?** From the little I know of Shelley's life, John Keats seems like a good candidate, but Shelley's descriptions are vague enough that they could be made to fit several figures.

---

On a side note: Shelley refers to **'the Preacher'** in the poem's last line. Is this a reference to Ecclesiastes? (I presume it's not a reference to *Poltergeist II: The Other Side*!)

Comment: It seems to me that the person who lifted the veil was not unhappy, but was separated from others, but special. What do you think? Also, who is the Preacher? I'm writingabout the different versions of The Painted Veil (film). Thanks for commenting on this sonnet.

Comment: Could Shelley have been talking about himself? He was an atheist.

Comment: It's certainly a possibility, but I have not yet come across any evidence to back this up. It would be a bit big-headed - even by Shelley's standards! But then again I'm hardly a Shelley scholar.

Comment: "[not any specific historical personage, but a generic quester](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mtqvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA18)" — Ronald Tetreault (1991). "Shelley: Style and Substance". In G. Kim Blank, ed. *The New Shelley: Later Twentieth-Century Views*, p. 18. Palgrave Macmillan.

Comment: As to the side note: I'd be super-surprised if "the Preacher" _weren't_ the author of Ecclesiastes.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Indeed. The more I think about it, the more 'the Preacher' *has* to be the narrator of Ecclesiastes. You're definitely ruling out *Poltergeist II* then, eh?

Comment: @GarethRees It's interesting to read the opinion of a professional scholar on this matter, but isn't Tetreault just speculating in that quotation? But then I suppose it would be rather difficult to produce concrete evidence that 'the one who had lifted it' is no-one in particular.

Comment: I would say that "the Preacher" represents all those who look for the truth in religion, as opposed to the subject of the sonnet, who looked for the truth in some other realm.

Comment: @PeterShor I don't think so. Those searching for truth in religion often find it - at least from their own point of view. The narrator of Ecclesiastes, on the other hand, remains baffled by the experience of being alive.

Comment: Yes, Tetreault can't be certain, but since he is an expert on Shelley I think his opinion is worth knowing -- if there were a well-known referent we would expect Tetreault to be aware of it.